# How companies assign the admin role to a user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, admin

I am coding a Rest API with express and I have a middleware to check if a user is admin or not. However, I wonder how companies assign a new user as an admin? Do they edit the database record and change the role there?. I guess that one admin could make another user admin but how is the first admin created? Is there a way to do it in the frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a software platform (meaning one web address and database for *all* users of your app) then the first admin user is typically created by running commands on the server command line console to create the right record. Or perhaps by a setup script that is run once. This creates the first admin user, and then that user logs in and creates more admin users via the UI. This typically only ever needs to be done once in the entire lifetime of the project, so no need to have this be a user friendly process.

However, if it's a server you install your own instance of it's common to have a setup wizard, since each new install will need to go through this process, it's worth the effort to make something user friendly. You go to something like `myapp.com/setup` and then complete a few forms that sets up the first admin user and provides initial configuration and preferences. After this first admin user is setup this `setup` page would no longer be accessible, so that no other new admin users can be created that way.

Wordpress is a great example of the interactive setup. The end of [this video](https://youtu.be/snFzbPm_RUE?t=626) has an example of what that looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I'm in the midst of building my back-end I'll throw my own name into the user (model) via the users (routes) to test the puppy out.. i use Postman to inject my info into the endpoints points, then keep it there on the (mongo)db.. you could always use atlas to manual insert the user as well.
EDIT: my answer: use atlas to manually input a json file with the admin user of your clients (the company) choosing.
EDIT2: you've got me thinking... there could be an initialization state of the web-app where these things are declared; for example, say yo're creating an accounting management tool, in the first of a company initializing their new software you could request this information.

Comment: Yes, I think they insert the user directly into the database, I can't think a way of doing that in a UI, you can't simply let the user choose their role with a select element. That would be crazy. However, once the first admin is created I think they could have some admin only routes to let this admin convert more users into admins.